# strange results while returning a Mat from a function call

Tags: c++, opencv

In the following function, the input argument is a 2 columns Mat matrice,
I loop through it and return a new matrice containing only non-zero elements.

```
Mat LaneDetector::getHigherThanZero(const Mat& X)
{

vector<Vec2f> XX;

for(int i = 0; i < X.rows; ++i)
{
    if(X.at<float>(i,1) > 0)
        XX.push_back(Vec2f(X.at<float>(i,0), X.at<float>(i,1)));
}
Mat Y = Mat(XX).reshape(1);
return Y;

}
```

When I run this in the main, everything is OK. When I call it from the main as follow:

```
Mat Y = getHigherThanZero(X);
cout << Y << endl;
```

I get some junk:

[image: call the function from main]

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `Mat` ? Have you check its copy/move constructor ?

Comment: Maybe because you did not implemented the copy constructor that you are using with "Mat Y = getHigherThanZero(X)"

Comment: Mat is `cv::Mat` - the copy constructor is implicitly already implemented in the base class.

Comment: Incidentally, -1.5883997e+038 corresponds to `0xFEEEFEEE`, a magic cookie which (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))) is "Used by Microsoft's debug HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory"

Comment: @SleuthEye - thanks but it doesn't help me to solve my problem :-)

Comment: Did you checked the value of the `Mat Y` inside the function?

Comment: Could it be that X is const yet you are having to cast to get the col & row values? X.at<float>(i,1)

Comment: @SHR - Yes, doing `cout << Y << endl;` gives the right result inside the function.

Comment: probably, `cv::Mat(XX)` doesnt copy the values of the vector but uses the data pointer (which is a very nice feature). after returning from the function, `XX` is out of scope. Try `return Y.clone()` which works for me!

Comment: @PhonoDots Hence why I didn't post as an answer, but it indicates a problem with using freed memory, which can typically be due to copy construction, and object construction/destruction in general as others have pointed out.

Comment: @PhonoDots you can try `return Mat(XX).reshape(1);` this way the destructor won't be called, I guess there a problem with the assign operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cv::Mat LaneDetector::getHigherThanZero(const cv::Mat& X)
{

    std::vector<cv::Vec2f> XX;

    for(int i = 0; i < X.rows; ++i)
    {
        if(X.at<float>(i,1) > 0)
            XX.push_back(cv::Vec2f(X.at<float>(i,0), X.at<float>(i,1)));
    }

    cv::Mat Y = cv::Mat(XX).reshape(1);

    return Y.clone();

}
```

your `XX` goes out of scope and `cv::Mat(XX)` doesn't copy the data, so you have to copy it yourself which is done by `.clone()`

EDIT: maybe there is a flag to copy the data from the input array/vector, so you could use that in the Mat constructor instead of calling the .clone later, but not sure about that!

EDIT 2: `cv::Mat Y = cv::Mat(XX).reshape(1).clone();` followed by a `return Y;` works too ;)

Comment: Better `return Mat(XX).reshape(1);` since Y not been used, so not need to clone.

Comment: imho it has nothing to do with the destructor of cv::Mat but with the destructor of std::vector. Since `.reshape` doesn't copy the values and `cv::Mat(XX)` doesn't copy the values, they are only present in the vector which goes out of scope.

Comment: but maybe there is a flag to copy the array/vector data directly on Mat construction, not sure about that...

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator) `operator=` makes a shallow copy of the matrix. Although it is stated, that there is some sort of reference counting it is quite possible that this is not implemented well enough. You should try:

```
Mat Y(getHigherThanZero(X));
```